# Im Trying To Assign User Id In Flutter Use Map Funcuin

Tags: flutter

Im Trying To Assign User Id  In Flutter Use Map Funcuin

```
Get Error
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuyrt.png

Comment: Hi there, please dont use images for displaying your code. Copy paste your code into your question, mark it and press CTRL + K to mark it as code (alternatively use the Stackoverflow GUI - the curly braces)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.